# Fabric js: zoomable canvas unwillingly changes text color when zooming

Tags: fabricjs

I used the code from their official site for zooming.

```
function make_canvas_zoomable(canvas, canvas_width, canvas_height) {
  canvas.on('mouse:wheel', function (opt) {
    var delta = opt.e.deltaY
    var zoom = canvas.getZoom()
    zoom *= 0.999 ** delta
    if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20
    if (zoom < 1) zoom = 1
    canvas.zoomToPoint({ x: opt.e.offsetX, y: opt.e.offsetY }, zoom)
    opt.e.preventDefault()
    opt.e.stopPropagation()
    var vpt = this.viewportTransform
    if (zoom < 0.4) {
      vpt[4] = 200 - (canvas_width * zoom) / 2
      vpt[5] = 200 - (canvas_height * zoom) / 2
    } else {
      if (vpt[4] >= 0) {
        vpt[4] = 0
      } else if (vpt[4] < canvas.getWidth() - canvas_width * zoom) {
        vpt[4] = canvas.getWidth() - canvas_width * zoom
      }
      if (vpt[5] >= 0) {
        vpt[5] = 0
      } else if (vpt[5] < canvas.getHeight() - canvas_height * zoom) {
        vpt[5] = canvas.getHeight() - canvas_height * zoom
      }
    }
  })
  canvas.on('mouse:down', function (opt) {
    var evt = opt.e
    if (evt.button === 0 || evt.button === 2) {
      this.isDragging = true
      this.selection = false
      this.lastPosX = evt.clientX
      this.lastPosY = evt.clientY
    }
  })
  canvas.on('mouse:move', function (opt) {
    if (this.isDragging) {
      var e = opt.e
      var zoom = canvas.getZoom()
      var vpt = this.viewportTransform
      if (zoom < 0.4) {
        vpt[4] = 200 - (canvas_width * zoom) / 2
        vpt[5] = 200 - (canvas_height * zoom) / 2
      } else {
        vpt[4] += e.clientX - this.lastPosX
        vpt[5] += e.clientY - this.lastPosY
        if (vpt[4] >= 0) {
          vpt[4] = 0
        } else if (vpt[4] < canvas.getWidth() - canvas_width * zoom) {
          vpt[4] = canvas.getWidth() - canvas_width * zoom
        }
        if (vpt[5] >= 0) {
          vpt[5] = 0
        } else if (vpt[5] < canvas.getHeight() - canvas_height * zoom) {
          vpt[5] = canvas.getHeight() - canvas_height * zoom
        }
      }
      this.requestRenderAll()
      this.lastPosX = e.clientX
      this.lastPosY = e.clientY
    }
  })
  canvas.on('mouse:up', function () {
    this.setViewportTransform(this.viewportTransform)
    this.isDragging = false
    this.selection = true
  })
}
```

When I mouse wheel and cursor is on the text, it color changes and becomes more transparent. When I disable canvas.on('mouse:wheel') logic, it doesn't happen when mouse wheeling on the text.

```
this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas(this.$refs.scanCanvas, {
        preserveObjectStacking: true,
        selection: false,
      })
```

That's how I init canvas

```
let actual_text = new fabric.Text(string_data.text, {
                  fontFamily: 'Comic Sans',
                  fontSize: this.draw_text_font_size,
                  fill: color,
                  left: actual_text_x,
                  top: centroid['y'] + 5,
                  backgroundColor: background_color,
                  selectable: false,
                })

                this.canvas.add(actual_text)
```

That's how I add text.

So I don't want my text to change color when mouse wheeling to zoom into or out.

Comment: Background color stays the same